# Unable to load or install the Bsgenome packages into R - macOS - error: invalid class "TwoBitFile" object: undefined class for slot "resource"

Tags: r, bioconductor

Unsure when exactly this started, but I have recently encountered the following error when I try to load the Bsgenome mouse or human. I have tried a fresh install of human, but it does not install properly

```
BiocManager::install("BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38")
Bioconductor version 3.11 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Installing package(s) 'BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38'
installing the source package ‘BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.11/data/annotation/src/contrib/BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38_1.4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 721596676 bytes (688.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 688.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning messages:
1: package ‘BiocGenerics’ was built under R version 4.0.3 
2: package ‘S4Vectors’ was built under R version 4.0.3 
3: package ‘IRanges’ was built under R version 4.0.3 
4: package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ was built under R version 4.0.3 
5: package ‘GenomicRanges’ was built under R version 4.0.3 
6: package ‘XVector’ was built under R version 4.0.3 
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Warning: package ‘BiocGenerics’ was built under R version 4.0.3
Warning: package ‘S4Vectors’ was built under R version 4.0.3
Warning: package ‘IRanges’ was built under R version 4.0.3
Warning: package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ was built under R version 4.0.3
Warning: package ‘GenomicRanges’ was built under R version 4.0.3
Warning: package ‘XVector’ was built under R version 4.0.3
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38', details:
  call: validObject(.Object)
  error: invalid class “TwoBitFile” object: undefined class for slot "resource" ("characterORconnection")
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/xr/lmkkh0p10t948k1n104z1jsh0000gn/T/RtmpFs9p2u/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38’ had non-zero exit status
```

And when I try to load mouse I get the following error

```
library(BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10', details:
  call: validObject(.Object)
  error: invalid class "TwoBitFile" object: undefined class for slot "resource" ("characterORconnection")
In addition: Warning message:
package 'XVector' was built under R version 4.0.3
```

sessionInfo() below

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the rn6 genome, maybe an object in these packages may need a version update.

Comment: I don't know exactly what fixed the problem for me, but in the end I was able to resolve by doing a fresh re-install of R and all my libraries.

Comment: To install the packages now that are very large, like genomes, I have to `install.packages(pkgname.tar.gz, repos = NULL, type ="source")`